# Update Website Data/information using a remote file

Tags: web

How would you suggest that i could update a website using a remote file in a computer or a separate file. The website i will be implementing this onto was made using html/css and i would want to update the content on the website using a remote file in my computer (say like a text document).

Basically what will be happening is the website will be pulling the data from a file that i will be able to update easily and the data will be displayed on the website.

I am trying my best to explain this as much as i can so please forgive me if it isnt clear enough. Any suggestions that you have are greatly appreciated :) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for Ajax. This names a technology which enables you to fetch and parse remote contents and display it within an existing html structure.